# USB: Reducing HID latency/buffering - Linux

Tags: linux, usb, delay, hid, latency

I have to transfer sensor data via micro-controller (Teensy 3.6 - Cortex M4) to a host PC with as little latency as possible (~1-2ms).

To test my communication I wrote a program that sends a counter via raw HID from the uC to the PC and then polls for a response. On the other side the PC receives the usb packet (containing the counter) and sends it back again. (I'm limited to libusb v0.1)

First I noticed that the sent back counter has not the same number as the one I just send but is roughly 4 numbers (transfers) older. To me this looks like buffering being made somewhere, something like a FIFO of size 4. I've tried to play with the rawHID values in the usb descriptor ([usb_desc.h](https://github.com/apmorton/teensy-template/blob/master/teensy3/usb_desc.h#L398%22usb_desc.h%22)) But reducing the Buffer amount i.e `NUM_USB_BUFFERS = 12` to 8 (min x2 buffers per endpoint) does nothing. Also regarding sheer pollingrate `RAWHID_TX_INTERVAL` ist set to `1` already, so the device is going to be polled every 1ms.

My best guess is that this has to do with some linux config, I just can't seem to find anything related to setting the amount of USB buffers or increasing USB throughput. Also I'm running linux with `CONFIG_HZ_1000` so ~1-2ms should be ... achievable?

I'd appreciate any feedback/suggestions on this matter.

Comment: What is the minimum USB standard your device will adhere to?  IIRC, the lowest polling rate you can have on USB is 1ms, but that's just the time between being asked the question: do you have data for me?  The way to specify what you need is the edit the descriptor of the device to say that you need to be polled at a 1ms interval.  It's part of the standard descriptor endpoint.  Also, that was for USB 1.1/2.  I'm not sure what's possible with 3.0 or better.

Comment: I'm targeting USB 2.0. Yes, the descriptor (see usb_desec.h) is specifying ``#define RAWHID_TX_INTERVAL 1`` already. What I'm mainly concerned is that the packet the PC is receiving is about 4 transfers old and not the one I just send.